# JSON reply from server

Tags: android, json

I am writing an android application with eclipse. I can connect to the server to get a json respond. However, my respond look like this.

```
\n\n{"product_id":"200003578","category":"Jacket","price":"799","description":"Wool blended, Pea","details":"73% Wool, 27 Nylon"}\n
```

which cannot be resolved by eclipse and return exception.

Is anyone know how can i deal with this respond and resolve it into an array?

Here is my php code:

```
 include ("db3.inc");

$sql = "SELECT * from product WHERE product_id='200003578'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$product_id=$array['product_id'];


echo json_encode( $array );
```

Here is the code i used for decode json respond.

```
    String product_id = null;
    String colour_id = null;
    String colour= null;
    String picture= null;
    try{
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(z);
    JSONObject json_data=null;
    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            product_id=json_data.getString("product_id");
            colour_id=json_data.getString("colour_id");
            colour=json_data.getString("colour");
            picture=json_data.getString("picture");

    }
    }catch(JSONException e1){
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Food Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    myActivity.text.setText(product_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a `JSONObject` not `JSONArray`, it should be parsed as:

```
JSONObject json_data=new JSONObject(yourstring.trim());
product_id=json_data.getString("product_id");
colour_id=json_data.getString("colour_id");
colour=json_data.getString("colour");
picture=json_data.getString("picture");
```

check http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: what if i dunno the respond consist of one object or two object(i.e. an array of object). How can i deal with this case?

Comment: I don't know enough about php and json to know why json_encode( $array ); emitted an object instead of array, but if you don't know if the server will be emitting an array or an object, you could try parsing it both ways and take the result that doesn't throw an exception.